# Mysterious Apache/PHP popen memory leak

Tags: php, file, popen, file-descriptor

I've been working on simulating multitasking in PHP using `popen`. The idea is that I put the part of the code that needs to run multiple times simultaneously in a different file, run that file with `popen` once for every time I need it run, feeding in input data using command line arguments, and then loop through the file handles until they've all returned their data.

As part of the debugging process, I've run this application around a hundred times, each time calling `popen` about 50 times. Usually, the resource is `pclose`'d at the end, but occasionally an error or `exit` is hit and the resource is left open at script end.

For some reason around an hour ago `popen` suddenly stopped working when trying to open that file. I also noticed that if I reduce the `popen`'s to one and `echo` out the handle, instead of starting numbering at `Resource id #2` (I also have a database connection open), the resources start at `Resource id #10`. To me, this says that perhaps there are some leaked descriptors somewhere.

How do I close these descriptors given I no longer have a variable referencing them?